# Bottom align and bottom clip a view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to clip a view that should be bottom aligned.

For example, we can have a view that is top clipped by using a negative top margin:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_marginTop="-20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I want to bottom-align the ImageView in my case, then push it down by 20 dp.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but since the parent view is wrapping the height, the extra margin just increases the height of the parent view, instead of having the ImageView get clipped. I need to leave the height of the parent as wrap_content.

I can do this with a custom view of course, just wondering if there's a way to do this without having to go that route.

Thanks